# Best StackExchange site for asking about carousel and accessibility

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, accessibility

I'm implementing a carousel slider that I want to make accessible, and I want to get feedback from screen reader users about their preferred way of navigating a carousel slider.

What's the best StackExchange site to ask this question on?

Comment: Asking for feedback like this is off-topic for any Stack Exchange. You can ask a more general question on the [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) site, but be sure to read their help center documentation about what is and is not on-topic.

Comment: As a mod on UX, yes I agree with @Oded. The topic itself is very much suited to UX, but providing individual reviews of implementations is not really ideal. However we'd welcome questions about accessibility and carousels if they haven't already been covered.